# An Actor "queue"?

Tags: scala

In Java, to write a library that makes requests to a server, I usually implement some sort of dispatcher (not unlike the one found here in the Twitter4J library: http://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-core/src/main/java/twitter4j/internal/async/DispatcherImpl.java) to limit the number of connections, to perform asynchronous tasks, etc.

The idea is that N number of threads are created.  A "Task" is queued and all threads are notified, and one of the threads, when it's ready, will pop an item from the queue, do the work, and then return to a waiting state.  If all the threads are busy working on a Task, then the Task is just queued, and the next available thread will take it.

This keeps the max number of connections to N, and allows at most N Tasks to be operating at the same time.

I'm wondering what kind of system I can create with Actors that will accomplish the same thing?  Is there a way to have N number of Actors, and when a new message is ready, pass it off to an Actor to handle it - and if all Actors are busy, just queue the message?

Comment: What you're describing is a thread pool, since Java 5 it's in the standard library, see package `java.util.concurrent` (class `ThreadPoolExecutor`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Akka Framework](http://doc.akkasource.org/)** is designed to solve this kind of problems, and is exactly what you're looking for. 
Look thru this [docu](http://doc.akkasource.org/dispatchers) - there're lots of highly configurable dispathers (event-based, thread-based, load-balanced, work-stealing, etc.) that manage actors mailboxes, and allow them to work in conjunction. You may also find interesting [this blog post](http://vasilrem.com/blog/software-development/flexible-load-balancing-with-akka-in-scala/).

E.g. this code instantiates new Work Stealing Dispatcher based on the fixed thread pool, that fulfils load balancing among the actors it supervises:

```
  val workStealingDispatcher = Dispatchers.newExecutorBasedEventDrivenWorkStealingDispatcher("pooled-dispatcher")
  workStealingDispatcher
  .withNewThreadPoolWithLinkedBlockingQueueWithUnboundedCapacity
  .setCorePoolSize(16)
  .buildThreadPool
```

Actor that uses the dispatcher:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

    messageDispatcher = workStealingDispatcher

    def receive = {
      case _ =>
    }
  }
```

Now, if you start 2+ instances of the actor, dispatcher will balance the load between the mailboxes (queues) of the actors (actor that has too much messages in the mailbox will "donate" some to the actors that has nothing to do).

Comment: I think you can do the same with Scala actors that override the scheduler method

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to see about the actors scheduler, as actors are not usually 1-to-1 with threads. The idea behind actors is that you may have many of them, but the actual number of threads will be limited to something reasonable. They are not supposed to be long running either, but rather quickly answering to messages they receive. In short, the architecture of that code seems to be wholly at odds with how one would design an actor system.

Still, each working actor may send a message to a Queue actor asking for the next task, and then loop back to react. This Queue actor would receive either queueing messages, or dequeuing messages. It could be designed like this:

```
val q: Queue[AnyRef] = new Queue[AnyRef]
loop {
  react {
    case Enqueue(d) => q enqueue d
    case Dequeue(a) if q.nonEmpty => a ! (q dequeue)
    }
}
```